# command line solution build using devenv rebuilding more projects than visual studio solution build

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd, msbuild, devenv

I am trying to mimic visual studio solution build from command prompt using batch script but there is significant difference between manual solution build(ctrl+shift+b) inside visual studio and command line solution build using devenv in terms of project rebuild counts. More projects are getting rebuilt from command line in comparison to visual studio solution build.

I am using this for command line build in batch file:

```
call"C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
devenv solution_name.sln /build "Debug"
```

command line solution build output looks like this: [devenv solution build using cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64odJ.png)

visual studio solution build output looks like this: [manual vs solution build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLzqV.png)

I have tried changing the configurations too but it didn't help, I am curious why this might be happening and is there a way to get same result from command line build as of manual vs solution build?